# What to do if sql connection is exhaust to due to load

Tags: mysql, configuration

Can Someone tell me what to do if all database connection exhaust due to load. Even though if is connection pool is implemented and it is also exhaust. Here i am trying find out the solution what should be correct approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

(You need to provide more details.)

If you have slow queries, speed them up.  Sometimes it is as simply as adding an index.  Let's see some of the lengthy queries in `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.

If you have a low value of `max_connections`, that can be raised.  But, if you have more than, say, 20 *running* connections (not just `Sleep`), this change is likely to hurt, not help.  (Think of a grocery store that is crowded; would you want to encourage more people to go in?)

How much RAM?  How big is the dataset?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 'main' table.